# Feed Mxnet Rec to Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mxnet

I have created **Mxnet** Rec data through **Im2rec**. I would like to feed this into **Tensorflow**. Is it possible ? and How would i do that? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably feed the data. 
You will need to use MXNet Iterators to get the data out of the records, and then each record you will need to cast to something that Tensorflow understands.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data out of the records, you can use the following python script. Maybe it would be helpful for someone who already has `.rec` file.

```
import numpy as np
import mxnet as mx
import cv2 as cv

index = 1

imgrec = mx.recordio.MXIndexedRecordIO('file.idx', 'file.rec', 'r')
header, s = mx.recordio.unpack(imgrec.read_idx(index))
img = mx.image.imdecode(s).asnumpy()
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
filename = '{}.jpg'.format(index)
cv.imwrite(filename, img)
```